# Why are polynuclear carbonyl complexes coloured?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, carbonyl-complexes

We know that polynuclear carbonyls are colored and their intensity increases with increase in metal ions. But why does the color arise?

I am aware that this is due to some transition between electronic energy levels; but, **what sort of transition takes place?** 
Is it due to transition between orbitals that are largely localized on the ligands *i.e.* CO, or is due to transition between orbitals localized on metal frame work?

I have tried gathering some information about the same and I have found something called metal to ligand charge transfer (MLCT) that is responsible for colors in complexes, but I am not sure whether this is applicable in this case or not.

Comment: Related: [Colorless nature of (mononuclear) carbonyl complexes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37529/colorless-nature-of-carbonyl-complexes)